# api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU - net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, почему

```
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

не открывается уже 2 дня?

Ошибка - api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU - net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: Adblock, антивирус, ошибка в сети, что-то ещё. Точно никакого отношения к javascript

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за объяснения. 
Но доступ все же прикрыли со стороны яндекса.

Ответ техподдержки:
Домен заблокирован за неоднократное превышение суточного лимита запросов к сервису геокодирования.

А по поводу ERR_ABORTED - браузер выдавал 2 ошибки:

```
GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU net::ERR_ABORTED
GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU 403 (Forbidden)
```

И видимо первое вытекает из последнего.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался.
У Яндекс апи есть лимит подключений для каждого домена.
С того же сервера, но другого домена - скрипт открывается.

Comment: У  API Карт нет лимита подключений с домена. Ограничения действуют только на количество запросов к отдельным сервисам API в пределах суточного лимита. 
Как вам правильно написали выше - это сетевая ошибка, которая вообще не имеет отношения к API.

Comment: Желательно поподробнее.

Comment: Всё в документации: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/#limits

Comment: И уж точно апи не может ответить net::ERR_ABORTED

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы указали неверные параметры в запросе, например долготу или широту

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/808365)